# How to get started posting a question with Stack Overflow?

Tags: format

I know this is going to sound extremely stupid but I honestly cannot figure out how to post a question I have here for a program I am trying to make.

Whenever I paste my code into the code section this website tells me I have not formatted correctly. I triple check everything and it is all perfectly formatted. It is strange though because my code ends up being halfway into the place where I am suppose to describe the issue. So I am definitely doing this wrong.

Would somebody please walk me through a simple tutorial so I can finally ask my questions?

Comment: Have a look at [How to ask good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: When you paste your code, highlight it and press the 5th button to the right on the top toolbar ( looks like { } ), this will format your code for you.

Comment: By "formatted", it means that the code should be indented by four spaces so it shows up properly. Highlight the code and press the `{}` button. Also see [ask]. And note that questions about the site itself belong on Meta Stack Overflow, not here.

Comment: The formatting used on Stack Overflow (and GitHub, BitBucket, Jira, Reddit, etc) is called "Markdown". If you click on the `?` mark on the right-hand side of the editor, it offers all sorts of help.

Comment: See also [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/), where this question would be on-topic. There are lots of posts there about how to format questions.

Answer (score 1):

Honor to help you, I think you can first learn how to use markdown.
And this is two useful tutorial I read when I am learning.

- Perfect question : [WRITING THE PERFECT QUESTION](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
- Use Markdown effectively : [Markdown Getting Started](https://www.markdownguide.org/getting-started/)

As for the display of code you mention above, you can use triple ``` to surround the code like this

```py
import math
print('hello world')
```

Comment: This question is off-topic for Stack Overflow - please do not answer off-topic questions. It should be on Meta.

Comment: Thank you all for the advice. I am going to give this a go.